# Half slide in ChildViewController doesn't receive events

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I have a UITableViewController called A in storyboard, now I tried to slide in A on my mainviewcontroller.

_vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"A"];

In my `showMenu` method

```
[self addChildViewController:self.vc];
[self.view addSubview:self.vc.view];
[self.vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7 animations:^{
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(160, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
}];
```

I can slide in viewcontroller A. However whatever I try to do with A I get no response. How can I get A to respond to touch events?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
self.viewControllerA = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"A"];
    [self.viewControllerA.view setFrame:CGRectMake(160, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self addChildViewController:self.viewControllerA];
    [self.view addSubview:self.viewControllerA.view];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.50f animations:^{
        [self.viewControllerA.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.viewControllerA didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    }];
```